# how are compose services implemented?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am wondering how compose implements services. To my understanding, each thing that compose does could be done with the docker CLI. For example, creating container, binding volumes, exposing ports and joining them on networks.

The one thing that is a blackbox in my understanding is how compose achieves the concept of a service as a unit. So that when you specify `replicas` under the `deploy` key, you get DNS round-robin kind of load balancing, similar to when you specify `--endpoint-mode dnsrr` in with swarm.

Can this actually be achieved with CLI commands, or does compose do some tricks with the SDK? In both cases, my question would be what exactly happens there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the key here is network alias.

```sh
# create a network
docker network create services

# create 2 apps
docker run --name app1 --rm -d nginx
docker run --name app2 --rm -d nginx

# the magic happens here, both container 
# are connected to the network with the same alias
docker network connect --alias app services app1
docker network connect --alias app services app2

# finally make a dns query for app and get two A records back
docker run --network services --rm tutum/dnsutils dig app
```

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> app
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33977
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;app.                           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
app.                    600     IN      A       172.30.0.2
app.                    600     IN      A       172.30.0.3

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 28 23:11:48 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59
```